# Do I have to use "the" before the names of army branches when talking about serving in a particular army branch?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if I have to use *the* before the names of army branches when talking about serving in a particular army branch? For example:

> John's dad served in (**the**) artillery, but John serves in (**the**) infantry.

Comment: Most definitely. I would remove the parentheses.

Comment: The only exceptions might come when you refer to particular units, as in: John's dad served in **Bomber Command,** John's dad was assigned to **Second Squadron**. Note that these are not descriptions of military branches, but proper names.

Comment: This example sentence sounds a little odd.  Hard to describe why, maybe because you use "but" to compare where John's dad served in different periods of time, but you don't explicitly specify the time periods.  I would restate this as "John's dad served in the artillery, but **now** he serves in the infantry".  Or you could say "John's dad **used to** serve in the artillery, but **now** he serves in the infantry".

Comment: Also, where this sentence construction would make sense is if the two verbs contrasted.  For instance " Billy **failed** in the Navy, but he **excels** in the Army".

Comment: @mjjf Isn't 'he' John rather than his dad?

Comment: @katebunting You're right, that could have been the intention! I totally missed that possibility.  I suppose the meaning would be clearer if the sentence were said aloud so the words being stressed are obvious, or with more context.

Comment: Yes, that was actually my intention. My bad. I've edited the question.

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to anyone  use **the**. So, use the in this case since you are referring to any infantry/artillery

If you are referring to a specific, use ‘a’ or no article.

### What’s the difference? When to use ‘a’ and ‘the’ and no articles?

See if the question flows. Take this statement

> I was walking home when **a** girl approached me.

(Specific girl. Cannot be **no article** since it doesn’t flow)

> I am serving army in **the** United States

United States (US) is a particular country

> I love drinking **milk**.

Milk is uncountable. You only use:

> I love drinking **the milk**.

when you are referring to a specific brand/type of milk